# wordpress url rewriting issue for one page or post

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

```
 I need help on wordpress Rewirite url.
```

http://www.example.com/this-is-a-test-title/93/

http://www.example.com/this-is-a-test-title2/93/

http://www.example.com/this-is-a-test-title3/93/

All these urls should point to
http://www.example.com/?p=93

any string after example.com/%%%%%%/93 should needs to point to
http://www.example.com/?p=93

**Its should works only particular post id = 93 Only.**

Comment: u can add a rule in your .htaccess file

Comment: Helpful article http://www.gerillafilm.se/web/ultimate-htaccess-rewrite-tutorial-with-301-redirects/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use couple of rewrite rules in web site `.htaccess` file, this file should be placed in root server directory. The `mod_rewrite` is an Apache module for manipulating (rewriting) URLs. Frequently this means taking the URL requested by a visitor and sending them content at a different URL.

Example:

**Original URL:**
   http://www.example.com/old-page/

**Desired destination URL:**
   http://www.example.com/new-page/

The `.htaccess` syntax:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^old-page/?$ $1/new-page$2 [R=301,L]
```

More info [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/).

Comment: I am creating the url dynamically by code. but it should go to that page only.

Comment: OK, the above rewrite rule takes this into consideration, substitute it with your `/93/`, instead of `old-page` and with `?p=93` instead `new-page`, keep however the `^` sign and other specials

Answer (score 0):

Create an .htaccess and add the below rules in the file

```
Redirect 301 /this-is-a-test-title/93/ http://www.example.com/?p=93
Redirect 301 /this-is-a-test-title2/93/ http://www.example.com/?p=93
Redirect 301 /this-is-a-test-title3/93/ http://www.example.com/?p=93
```

Answer (score 0):

there are plugins which help with these kind of redirects.
For e.g.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/